# How to run functions in an ordered sequence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution to ensure that the three functions that I created run in an ordered sequrence once the first has completed.

Currently I have something like this which does not seem to work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(runPending(selectedYear, name)).then(runApproved(selectedYear,name)).then(runRejected(selectedYear,name));

});


function runPending(year, name){
    var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(URL, function() {
    }).done(function(json) {
        if(json.length == 0){
            console.log("No Data came back!");
        }
        else{
            //do stuff set to html_output_pending;

            $('#display').append(html_output_pending);
            }//end else

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function runApproved(year, name){
    var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(URL, function() {
    }).done(function(json) {
        if(json.length == 0){
            console.log("No Data came back!");
        }
        else{
            //do stuff set to html_output_pending;

            $('#display').append(html_output_pending);
            }//end else

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function runRejected(year, name){
    var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(URL, function() {
    }).done(function(json) {
        if(json.length == 0){
            console.log("No Data came back!");
        }
        else{
            //do stuff set to html_output_pending;

            $('#display').append(html_output_pending);
            }//end else

    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

How do I ensure that once runPending has been completed and appended its data to the div element #display, execute the second function in order to the third.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Javascript doesn't multitask. Unless you are doing asynchronious calls in your functions or they fire handlers with logic you rely on, then simply calling each function would work.

Comment: @Vld I do a $.getJSON on each function. Perhaps that's what causing it?

Comment: That is absolutely causing it.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Indeed - AJAX calls would be the thing. if you do not rely on them being asynchroinious, you could flip the `async` flag to `false` but it might be a better idea if you attach the functions you need to the success handlers of each.

Comment: Correction - `getJSON` does not have an `async` flag. You would need to add them to the success handler.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript functions run sequentially, so:

```
$(function() {
   runPending(selectedYear, name);
   runApproved(selectedYear, name);
   runRejected(selectedYear, name);
}
```

Will work just fine.  If your `runPending`, `runApproved`, and `runRejected` functions are more complicated such that they are calling asynchronous functionality, they should return promises ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and $q implement them slightly differently).  This is when your promise chaining (when, then, then...) would be appropriate.

In the case of `$.getJson` as you have updated with, you would do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $.when(runPending(selectedYear, name))
   .then(runApproved(selectedYear, name))
   .then(runRejected(selectedYear, name));
}

function runPending(x,y){
    return $.getJson(someUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
    }
}

function runApproved(x,y){
    return $.getJson(someOtherUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
    }
}

function runRejected(x,y){
    return $.getJson(someThirdUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
    }
}
```

If what you are doing is very process-intensive such that the `done` handler may take longer than the following request/`done` handler, you could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $.when(runPending(selectedYear, name))
   .then(runApproved(selectedYear, name))
   .then(runRejected(selectedYear, name));
}

function runPending(x,y){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    $.getJson(someUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
        deferred.resolve('success');
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}

function runApproved(x,y){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    $.getJson(someOtherUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
        deferred.resolve('success');
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}

function runRejected(x,y){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    $.getJson(someThirdUrl).done(function(stuff) {
        $('#display').append(stuff);
        deferred.resolve('success');
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: is that same as having them in onload? Because if so, doesn't seem to be the case as they load in different order on each load

Comment: @Jaime Torres: What do you mean by run sequentially? What if one of those functions involved a network operation or a `setTimeout()`, that could cause the next function to start before the result of the previous one has completed.

Comment: In the example provided, he didn't have any asynchronous functionally in his code,but has eluded to it in his newer comments.

Comment: @JaimeTorres can you explain the reason behind "return" on each json when it is already appending the result to the div on call?

Comment: Sure, the return is retuning the promise so we know when to fire the next item.  The `done` is doing the work of the append once it's done.  Techincally, if you had an insanely fast response, you might run into a race-case where the items didn't append in the correct order.  If this is a concern (very small probability), you could create your own promise in the function, and then complete it in the `done` of each `getJson`.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo on line 3 of the second snippet, you have a semi-colon at the end of the line, but the next line begins with a "."

Comment: @Zack resolved.  Added more robust promises to allow for longer processing time within `done`.

Comment: @JaimeTorres I've added your third solution. Seems to return expected results on IE but not Chrome. Very strange. Any ideas? I'll update my code to show what I've done so far.

Comment: I'm surpassed it works in IE?  I don't see you resolving your promises in your example code.